# In assignment operator function, is array being memcpy implicitly

Tags: c++

OK. We know the following code cannot be compiled.

```
char source[1024];
char dest[1024];
// Fail. Use memcpy(dest, source, sizeof(source)); instead.
dest = source;
```

But, the following code can be compiled and behave correctly.

```
class A {
    char data[1024];
};
A source;
B dest;
dest = source;
```

I was wondering, in operator assignment function, is array will be memcpy implicitly?

The following are the complete test code.

---

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    char data[1024];
};

int main() {
    {
        A source;
        A dest;

        // Initialization
        char *data = "hello world";
        memcpy (source.data, data, strlen(data) + 1);

        printf ("source.data = %s\n", source.data);
        printf ("address source.data = %x\n", source.data);

        // Works! Does this in the operator assignment function, memcpy is
        // being performed implicitly on array.
        dest = source;

        printf ("dest.data = %s\n", dest.data);
        printf ("address dest.data = %x\n", dest.data);
    }

    {
        char source[1024];
        char dest[1024];

        // Initialization
        char *data = "hello world";
        memcpy (source, data, strlen(data) + 1);

        printf ("source = %s\n", source);
        printf ("address source = %x\n", source);

        // '=' : left operand must be l-value
        // dest = source;
        // Works with memcpy.
        memcpy(dest, source, sizeof(source));

        printf ("dest = %s\n", dest);
        printf ("address dest = %x\n", dest);
    }

    getchar();
}

//RESULT :
//source.data = hello world
//address source.data = 12fb60
//dest.data = hello world
//address dest.data = 12f758
//source = hello world
//address source = 12f344
//dest = hello world
//address dest = 12ef3c
```

Comment: There was a lot of discussion about why this is the case in [Why does C++ support memberwise assignment of arrays within structs but not generally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437110/why-does-c-support-memberwise-assignment-of-arrays-within-structs-but-not-gene)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

compiler generated copy-ctor / assignment-op is bitwise-copy if no copy-ctor / assignment-op found for the child elements.

**Edit**:
Here is the modified test case showing the concept.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>

class someElement
{
public:
    someElement() : theData(0) {}
    // Intentionally copy-edit
    someElement(const someElement& src) : theData(src.theData + 1) {}
    ~someElement(){}

    someElement& operator=(const someElement& rhs)
    {
        theData = rhs.theData - 1;
        return *this;
    }

    char    theData;
};

class A {
public:
    someElement data[1024];
};

int main() {
    {
        A source;
        A dest;

        // Initialization
        char *data = "hello world";
        memcpy (source.data, data, strlen(data) + 1);

        printf ("source.data = %s\n", source.data);
        printf ("address source.data = %x\n", source.data);

        // Works! Does this in the operator assignment function, memcpy is
        // being performed implicitly on array.
        dest = source;

        printf ("dest.data = %s\n", dest.data);
        printf ("address dest.data = %x\n", dest.data);
    }

    {
        someElement source[1024];
        someElement dest[1024];

        // Initialization
        char *data = "hello world";
        memcpy (source, data, strlen(data) + 1);

        printf ("source = %s\n", source);
        printf ("address source = %x\n", source);

        // '=' : left operand must be l-value
        // dest = source;
        // Works with memcpy.
        memcpy(dest, source, sizeof(source));

        printf ("dest = %s\n", dest);
        printf ("address dest = %x\n", dest);
    }

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: How is bitwise-copy being performed on array? Any reference source?

Comment: @Yan Cheng CHEOK: operator= is invoked for each element in turn. It is kind of recursive

Answer (score 9):

Does this quote from the Standard help? It is quiet self explanatory

Sorry, removed my earlier answer which was related to copy constructor and not copy assignment operator.

$12.8/30-

> The implicitly-defined copy assignment
>   operator for a non-union class X
>   performs memberwise copy assignment of
>   its subobjects. The direct base
>   classes of X are assigned first, in
>   the order of their declaration in the
>   base-specifier-list, and then the
>   immediate non-static data members of X
>   are assigned, in the order in which
>   they were declared in the class
>   definition. Each subobject is assigned
>   in the manner appropriate to its type:
>
> — if the subobject is of class type,
>   the copy assignment operator for the
>   class is used (as if by explicit
>   qualification; that is, ignoring any
>   possible virtual overriding functions
>   in more derived classes);
>
> **— if the
>   subobject is an array, each element is
>   assigned, in the manner appropriate to
>   the element type;**
>
> — if the subobject
>   is of scalar type, the built-in
>   assignment operator is used.

Answer (score 4):

`operator=`, if not explicitly implemented, performs a memberwise copy of the class's contents.  For your encapsulated array this will work but in general care is needed to ensure proper deep copying of the class's data.

Comment: note that it is not bitwise copy if the member has assignment-op.

Comment: No.  It performs a member-wise copy.  This is necessary since nested types may have their own operator=() at any depth in the nesting hierarchy.  Their operator=() could have any number of side-effects outside of the range of bits that a bitwise copy would affect.  These side-effects are guaranteed to happen.  So, no, the copy is not bitwise.

Comment: @Eric - thanks, updated the text and upvoted alternate answer