# The reason behind strict rule of passing an array by pointer to a function in C++ standard

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, standards, parameter-passing

In C++ the only way to pass an array to a function is by pointer, considering following
functions:

```
void someFunc(sample input[7]){
 //whatever
}
void someFunc(sample input[]){
 //whatever
}
void someFunc(sample (& input)[7]){
 //whatever
}
```

All above function parameters are identical with following function parameter when the function is not inlined:

```
void someFunc(sample * input){
 //whatever
}
```

Now to pass the array with value we have to put it in a structure like below:

```
struct SampleArray{
 public:
  sample sampleArray[7];
};
```

Now I'd like to know if anyone knows the reason behind this design in C++ standard that makes passing pure arrays by value impossible by any syntax and forces to use structs.

Comment: Probably not the only reason - may not even be the main reason - but if the size of `sample` was huge, e.g., 1 MB, passing an array of 7 `sample` objects by value would not be efficient and would blow the default stack.

Answer (score 2):

Backward compatibility reasons. C++ had no choice but to inherit this behavior from C.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437110/why-does-c-support-memberwise-assignment-of-arrays-within-structs-but-not-gene/3438004#3438004) to the earlier similar question addresses the reasons why such behavior was introduced in C (or, more specifically, why arrays and arrays within structs are handled differently by the language).

C++ adopted that part of C, but added the ability to pass arrays by reference (note that your third version of `someFunc` passes the array by reference, and is not equivalent to using a pointer to its first element). In addition, C++ includes various container types that can be passed by value (recently including `std::array`)

Answer (score 0):

Probably as a function of its C ancestry. Arrays being just pointers to memory it'd be kind of hard for that to be done transparently without generating extra code by the compiler. Also it's trivial to implement a container class that does lazy copy on write, which will perform better.