# Assigning array and struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does C++ support memberwise assignment of arrays within structs, but not generally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437110/why-does-c-support-memberwise-assignment-of-arrays-within-structs-but-not-gen)

In C language, `struct` can be copied by **immediate assignment** but `array` can't.

```
int a[2] = {1, 2};
int a2[2] = a; /*illegal*/
int *p = a; /*assigned by reference*/

struct S {int i; int j;};
struct S s = {1, 2};
struct S s2 = s; /*assigned by value*/
```

What are the **design advantages** in C language to differentiate the assignment of `array` and `struct`?

**@EDIT**

In fact, we usually think of passing by value when invoking C functions like many other languages, but if the argument is of `array`, it's effectively passed by reference.

```
struct S {int i; int j;};
void pass_by_value(struct S s);
struct S s2 = {1, 2};
pass_by_value(s2); /* s2 is copied to s */

void pass_by_ref(int a[]);
int a2[] = {1, 2};
pass_by_ref(a2); /* a2 is referenced to a */
```

There's a **syntax sugar** for `array` pervasive in C programming:

```
array_var == &array_var
```

If we want a new language feature that `array` can be copied like `struct` by **immediate assignment**, the legacy code will then definitely broken. Is this one of the major obstacles to have a clonable `array` in C?

Comment: Technically, none of those lines you show are _assignments_, they are _initialization_. You couldn't do `int a[2]; a = { 1, 2 };` though `int a[2] = { 1, 2 };` is legal, and with `struct`s you can't do `struct S { int i; int j; } s; s = { 1, 2 };` either, though you can do `s = (struct S){ 1, 2 };` in C99.

Answer (score 1):

In pre-K&R C `struct` objects were also not assignable. When this was changed, arrays were also considered but it was noticed the C standard needed to many changes to accommodate this for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can even do:

```
struct S {
   int a[2];
};
```

and assign them easily. So arrays can be assigned indirectly, if you wrap them in a struct.