# Error when assigning Array in Constructor

Tags: c++, c, arrays, gcc, constructor

Here's a weird issue I'm facing - probably something ultra-basic given my rusty C++ skills but I'm still perplexed :

- I've got a class
- We've also got an array of `unsigned long long`s in this class - let's call that `arr`

**My Class Interface :**

```
typedef unsigned long long U64;

class DQClass
{
    public:
        DQClass (void);
        virtual ~DQClass (void);

        U64 arr[12];
};
```

Now as for the implementation...

**Test 1 (This works) :**

```
DQClass::DQClass (void)
{
        this->arr[0] = 0x8100000000000000ULL;
        this->arr[1] = 0x4200000000000000ULL;

        // and so on..
}
```

**Test 2 (This doesn't) :**

```
DQClass::DQClass (void)
{
    this->arr = 
    {
        0x8100000000000000ULL,
        0x4200000000000000ULL,
        0x2400000000000000ULL,
        0x1000000000000000ULL,
        0x0800000000000000ULL,
        0x00FF000000000000ULL,
        FLIPV(0x8100000000000000ULL),
        FLIPV(0x4200000000000000ULL),
        FLIPV(0x2400000000000000ULL),
        FLIPV(0x1000000000000000ULL),
        FLIPV(0x0800000000000000ULL),
        FLIPV(0x00FF000000000000ULL)
    };
}
```

**Error :**

```
dqclass.cpp: In constructor ‘DQClass::DQClass()’:
dqclass.cpp:28: error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token
dqclass.cpp:28: error: expected `;' before ‘{’ token
```

---

Why isn't this working? Shouldn't it be working in the same fashion as, e.g. `U64 someArr[12] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}` would?

Any ideas?

Comment: what if you move the `{` to the same line as the `=` ?

Comment: @NahumLitvin I would be really surprised if something like that worked... And nope, it doesn't.

Comment: Arrays are broken in C++ (because they are broken in C).  That's why things like `std::vector` and `std::array` were invented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays can't be assigned like that (or any other way), only initialized:

```
 // sorry for bad formatting
DQClass::DQClass (void)
: arr(
    {
        0x8100000000000000ULL,
        0x4200000000000000ULL,
        0x2400000000000000ULL,
        0x1000000000000000ULL,
        0x0800000000000000ULL,
        0x00FF000000000000ULL,
        FLIPV(0x8100000000000000ULL),
        FLIPV(0x4200000000000000ULL),
        FLIPV(0x2400000000000000ULL),
        FLIPV(0x1000000000000000ULL),
        FLIPV(0x0800000000000000ULL),
        FLIPV(0x00FF000000000000ULL)
    }) {
}
```

Use constructor initialize list.

---

You could also use `std::array`:

```
std::array<U64, 12> arr;

// ...

this->arr = 
    {{
        0x8100000000000000ULL,
        0x4200000000000000ULL,
        0x2400000000000000ULL,
        0x1000000000000000ULL,
        0x0800000000000000ULL,
        0x00FF000000000000ULL,
        FLIPV(0x8100000000000000ULL),
        FLIPV(0x4200000000000000ULL),
        FLIPV(0x2400000000000000ULL),
        FLIPV(0x1000000000000000ULL),
        FLIPV(0x0800000000000000ULL),
        FLIPV(0x00FF000000000000ULL)
    }};
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to say in your first piece of code... Could please explain to me why `U64 someArr[12] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}` **does** work?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Initialization is different from assignment. Arrays have silly behavior and so I can't give you a good reason why arrays can't be assigned. Just use `std::array` for such purposes.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437110/why-does-c-support-memberwise-assignment-of-arrays-within-structs-but-not-gen

Comment: OK, here's another interesting issue : I decided to try the `std::array` way. While trying `#include <array>`, I'm getting `error: array: No such file or directory` and `ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘array’ with no type`. (Hint : using `g++` in Mac OS X 1.6.8)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon You need a fairly recent version that supports C++11. You could also try `boost::array` which is what `std::array` is based off of.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was thinking right now. I'm making fairly extensive use of Boost anyway, so it will do no harm... Thanks a lot for your help, buddy! ;-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: Include `<array>` and add the flag `-std=c++0x`.  If you're not using a C++11 compiler, the code in Pubby's answer won't work even with `boost::array`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Still comes with an error : `cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Note that `g++ --version` gives : `i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)`

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon If you are not using C++11 you are missing out. Upgrade 4.7 or latest Clang if you can. (I realize this is not always possible)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: You're out of luck then, unless you can update your compiler.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley+Pubby OK, guys! Thanks a lot for your help! It's been some time that I've been working full-time with Objective-C code that I've forgotten what it is to be working with C++ and I keep thinking it's always my fault... lol Guess I'll have to see what I can do with upgrading the compiler, then. Thanks, again! :-)