# Why can't I assign an array variable directly to another array variable with the '=' operator?

Tags: c++, arrays, char-pointer

Why does the following assignment not work? I would like a low-level explanation if possible.  Also, here's the compiler error I get: incompatible types in assignment of 'char*' to 'char [20]'

```
class UCSDStudent {

  char name[20];

  public:

    UCSDStudent( char name[] ) {
      //this-> name = name; does not work! Please explain why not
      strcopy( this -> copy, copy ); //works 
    }

};
```

Comment: Because C isn't all prettied up like Java (a shame that C++ had to inherit that imo). C++ mostly is if you use C++ features instead of C.

Comment: Because of C and pointers.

Comment: Well guys, I'm not gonna lie, I deduced that much on my own.

Comment: The moral of the story being that you can't complain about C++ here, only C. In C++, you have `std::string name;` and `this->name = name;`.

Comment: Perhaps this explanation of C++ [arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c) would suffice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does C++ support memberwise assignment of arrays within structs, but not generally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437110/why-does-c-support-memberwise-assignment-of-arrays-within-structs-but-not-gen)

Comment: @chris Thanks! That actually did answer my question. It literally says, "For no particular reason, arrays cannot be assigned to one another." lol.

Comment: Well, when you need arrays, there's always `std::array`. It supports assignment, among other things. `std::string` is what you should use here, though.

Answer (score 5):

Because when you have a function call like this `UCSDStudent( char name[] )` only the adress of the array `name` is copied instead of the whole array. It is a C\C++ feature.

Furthermore the `name` defined as `char name [20]` is not a modifiable lvalue.

Regarding `strcpy`: it will bring undefined behaivour as if your source array doesn't have a NULL character it will copy some trash to `this->name` too. You may read more about `strcpy` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/)

Comment: Even if you passed the array by reference, it still wouldn't work.

Comment: @chris I had a typo, it is not a lvalue.

Comment: Are you _certain_ `name` isn't an lvalue?

Comment: @chris my explanation refers to the error he has as it underlines why the thing inside his function is a `char*` so his logic (the Java one I assume) doesn't work.

Comment: `name`, in `char name[20]` is most certainly an lvalue.  Otherwise you wouldn't be able to take its address, like this: `char (*name_ptr)[20] = &name;`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley but you can't modify it.

Comment: I didn't say you could.  Modifiability is not a requirement for lvalue-ness.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yes, my mistake, I disregarded the word "modifiable", thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to assign array to array, use a loop.

for eg: 
    class UCSDStudent 
    {

```
char name[20];

public:

UCSDStudent( char name[] ) 
{

for(int i = 0; i<20; i++)
  {
  this-> name[i] = name[i];

  }
}
};
```

Comment: What if the parameter `name` has less then 20 characters?

Comment: please use proper indentation

Answer (score 1):

Because you assingned name as an array so you can not copy just like that and there is 21 count which name has. You must use "=" to copy an with loops and you have to identify array's count.

```
 for(int i = 0; i<20; i++){

  this -> name[i]=name[i];   
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this example.

```
int arr1[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

In case of C++, the array name `arr1` does not get a separate memory location. It's true that `arr1` sort of holds the memory location of `arr1[0]` but that is more of an oversimplification. The way arrays are referenced in C++ is via the symbol table. When an array is created,  corresponding to `arr1` an entry is created in the symbol table at compile time. This entry contains the information about the data-type of elements in  `arr1` (which here is an integer-type array) and the address of `arr1[0]`.
Now, here lies the interesting thing. Once an entry is created in the symbol table, C++ does not allow for it be changed.

If you do `arr1=arr2`, what you are essentially trying to do is reassign `arr1` to the entry corresponding to `arr2` in the symbol table. But `arr1` has already been assigned some value in the symbol table.   So C++ will give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

c-style arrays are not copyable like that, if you want to
copy one, you have to copy the content instead:

```
int arr1[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int arr2[10];
std::copy(arr1, arr1+10, arr2);
// std::copy() lives in <algorithm>
// content of arr2 is a now copy of arr1
```

However, low-level features like c-style arrays, are best avoided.

If what you really wanted was a variable length string, use `std::string`
instead, it supports copying via assignment operator.

If you really wanted a fixed length array, use `std::array<T,N>` instead,
it also supports copying via assignment operator.

Also note, a recommendation is that parameter names and member variable names are distinct, except for constructors where you use the member initialization syntax:

```
#include <string>

class UCSDStudent
{
    std::string name;
public:
    UCSDStudent( std::string name )
        : name(name)
    {
    }
    void SetName( std::string new_name )
    {
        name = new_name;
    }
};
```

Also note, if you planning on having setters and getters for all member
variables, may I recommend public data instead, at least if the class
does not have an [class-invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_invariant).