# Initializing char array from constant

Tags: c++

I'm starting with this code:

```
void func1() {
  char tmpfile[] = "/tmp/tmpXXXXXX";
  mkstemp(tmpfile);  // Note: mkstemp modifies the char array, cannot be const
  ...
}

void func2() {
  char tmpfile[] = "/tmp/tmpXXXXXX";
  mkstemp(tmpfile);  // Note: mkstemp modifies the char array, cannot be const
  ...
}
```

I'd like to refactor this to pull out the shared `"/tmp/tmpXXXXXX"` constant. Here is an attempt:

```
constexpr char kTmpfile[] = "/tmp/tmpXXXXXX";

void func1() {
  char tmpfile[] = kTmpfile;
  mkstemp(tmpfile);  // Note: mkstemp modifies the char array, cannot be const
  ...
}

void func2() {
  char tmpfile[] = kTmpfile;
  mkstemp(tmpfile);  // Note: mkstemp modifies the char array, cannot be const
  ...
}
```

However, this doesn't compile. Changing `tmpfile[]` to `tmpfile[sizeof(kTmpfile)]` also doesn't work.

The below *does* work, but it uses a macro which is discouraged by my company's style guide (which is based on the [Google Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Preprocessor_Macros)).

```
#define TMPFILE "/tmp/tmpXXXXXX"

void func1() {
  char tmpfile[] = TMPFILE;
  mkstemp(tmpfile);  // Note: mkstemp modifies the char array, cannot be const
  ...
}

void func2() {
  char tmpfile[] = TMPFILE;
  mkstemp(tmpfile);  // Note: mkstemp modifies the char array, cannot be const
  ...
}
```

Is there any way to write this "nicely"? Without having to use a macro or hardcode the size? Or is the macro the best option for readability and maintainability?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use `std::string`?

Comment: I'm using `mkstemp`, which expects you to pass it a char array (which it mutates). As far as I understand, code like `mkstemp(tmpfile.c_str())` is not allowed because manipulating a `std::string` through its `.c_str()` pointer produces UB.

Comment: As long as the `tmpfile` arrays are function-local, you should be able to replace `char tmpfile[] = STR_LITERAL;` with `char tmpfile[sizeof kTmpfile]; memcpy(tmpfile,kTmpfile,sizeof kTmpfile);` with no loss of efficiency.

Comment: @KerrickStaley then I'd write a nice wrapper for `mkstemp` that makes things more c++-esque. Something like `std::string my_mkstemp(std::string)` and then you can do all the ugliness of `strcpy`'ing into a char array and stuff in one place and reuse it everywhere.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ This question is different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182588/why-cant-i-assign-an-array-variable-directly-to-another-array-variable-with-the because the arrays here are constant. So there may be some solution here (e.g. using constexpr) that wouldn't be applicable to the other question.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ is can you please re-open the question?

Comment: @KerrickStaley Reopened. Still not a very good and well researched question though. Just use `std:string` maybe along with `std::string::data()` / `std::string::c_str()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I wasn't aware that std::string::data was an option. In C++14 and earlier, .data() returns a const pointer, and you're not allowed to modify the backing array through it. But in C++17 this is now allowed, which I didn't know. Mind writing up this answer and I'll accept it? If not, I can also write it up.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question shows a lack of understand of the C++ language that is unlikely to be of general interest.

Comment: @KerrickStaley At least `std::string::c_str()` was an option with the first c++ standard introduced.

Comment: @KerrickStaley There are some gotchas with that approach. It will still work well as a null-terminated string (which is what you need), but the reported `length` and `size` can differ from the length of the null-terminated string. In the olden days where there was only `const` bugger access, you could generally use `&str[0]` to get non-`const` access. Same caveats as before.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I need a `char*` (mutable, not `const`). Sorry, I should have made that clearer when asking the question. In C++17 `std::string::data()` will give you a `char*`, in earlier versions it returns a `const char*`. `std::string::c_str()` always returns a `const char*` I believe.

Comment: @PSkocik if you want to type up that answer as an option for C++14 and earlier, I'll upvote it

Answer (score 4):

Here are three approaches. Credit goes to @πάνταῥεῖ, @PSkocik, and @Asu for suggesting these, I just typed them up.

**Approach 1a**

```
constexpr auto kTmpfile = "/tmp/tmpXXXXXX";

void func1() {
  std::string tmpfile = kTmpfile;
  mkstemp(tmpfile.data());
  ...
}
```

Advantages:

- less code / more readable

Disadvantages:

- C++17 only, because `std::string::data` returns a `const char*` in C++14 and earlier (of course, you can use a `const_cast` in C++14, but that's also bad)
- may be slower, since char array may be allocated on the heap instead of stack

**Approach 1b**

```
constexpr auto kTmpfile = "/tmp/tmpXXXXXX";

void func1() {
  std::string tmpfile = kTmpfile;
  mkstemp(&tmpfile[0]);
  ...
}
```

Advantages:

- less code / more readable
- C++11 and later (see [Does "&s[0]" point to contiguous characters in a std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986966/does-s0-point-to-contiguous-characters-in-a-stdstring))

Disadvantages:

- may be slower, since char array may be allocated on the heap instead of stack

**Approach 2**

```
constexpr char kTmpfile[] = "/tmp/tmpXXXXXX";

void func1() {
  char tmpfile[sizeof(kTmpfile)];
  memcpy(tmpfile, kTmpfile, sizeof(kTmpfile));
  mkstemp(tmpfile);
  ...
}
```

Advantages:

- only uses stack, no heap
- compatible with C++14 and earlier

Disadvantages:

- more verbose / less readable

Comment: Why would the first approach be C++17 only? Looks like C++11 to me.

Comment: Because `.data` returns a const pointer in C++14 and earlier. Updated the answer to clarify.

Comment: `&data[0]` works an alternative to `.data()`. Thus the whole thing can be made compatible with C++03: do that and use `const char*` instead of `constexpr auto`.

Comment: I don't think `&data[0]` is guaranteed to work in C++03 or earlier, although in practice it will on pretty much any existing compiler. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986966/does-s0-point-to-contiguous-characters-in-a-stdstring

Comment: But I think you might be right, approach 1 can be modified by doing `&tmpfile[0]` in order to make it compatible with C++11 and later.

Comment: As I said in a now-dead question, I've never worked on a platform where `&stringvar[0]` didn't "work". I'm sure they exist. Never used one. "work" is quoted because there are a few caveats.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and some *template magic* to determine the array size;

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

constexpr char kTmpfile[] = "/tmp/tmpXXXXXX";

template<typename T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t array_size(T(&)[N])
{
    return N;
}

void func1() {
  std::array<char, array_size(kTmpfile)> var;
  std::copy(std::begin(kTmpfile), std::end(kTmpfile), var.begin());

  mkstemp(var.data());
  //...
}
```

To get to the data inside a `std::array` the function [`data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data) can be called.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the char arrays are local, you can replace

```
char tmpfile[] = STR_LITERAL;
```

with

```
char tmpfile[sizeof kTmpfile]; memcpy(tmpfile,kTmpfile,sizeof tmpfile);
```

with theoretically no loss of efficiency.

Clang, for example, [compiles both func1 and func2](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/JvKYkD) in the snippet below into the same instructions on x86_64:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int func1() {
  char tmpfile[] = "/tmp/tmpXXXXXX";
  mkstemp(tmpfile);
}

#include <string.h>
const char kTmpfile[] = "/tmp/tmpXXXXXX";
int func2() {
  char tmpfile[sizeof kTmpfile]; 
  memcpy(&tmpfile,kTmpfile,sizeof tmpfile);

  mkstemp(tmpfile);
}
```

Assembly output:

```
func1(): # @func1()
  subq $24, %rsp
  movabsq $24866934413088880, %rax # imm = 0x58585858585870
  movq %rax, 15(%rsp)
  movabsq $8101259051807896623, %rax # imm = 0x706D742F706D742F
  movq %rax, 8(%rsp)
  leaq 8(%rsp), %rdi
  callq mkstemp
func2(): # @func2()
  subq $24, %rsp
  movabsq $24866934413088880, %rax # imm = 0x58585858585870
  movq %rax, 15(%rsp)
  movabsq $8101259051807896623, %rax # imm = 0x706D742F706D742F
  movq %rax, 8(%rsp)
  leaq 8(%rsp), %rdi
  callq mkstemp
```

This solution for refactoring the duplicate initialization string without using macros also works in plain C.

Using `std::string`, while it would generally use the heap, which is quite a bit more expensive than the stack, shouldn't hurt here much either as you can expect the file creation to take at least a microsecond and thereby dominate over the heap allocation and string copy.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for digging into the assembly output and checking that it's the same!

Answer (score 1):

One more way, C++11 (or C++03 if you write a constructor):

```
struct KTmpfile { char value[...] = "/tmp/tmpXXXXXX"; };

void func1() {
    KTmpfile tmpfile;
    mkstemp(tmpfile.value);
    ...
}
```

Stack only, smallest code possible in the `func*` users.

Note that you have to specify the size of `value`, of course (or repeat the literal to find out the size).

---

In my view, this is the best way to do it, because what you really want is a type that you want to get several instances of -- you know its size and its initial value, so create a proper type for it.

And, at this point, since you have a type, you are one step into calling `mkstemp` from the type itself, maybe even in the constructor, and then simply say:

```
void func1() {
    KTmpfile tmpfile;
    ...
}
```