# Why can an initializer list only be used on declaration?

Tags: c++, arrays, initializer-list

Arrays can be initialized with what's called an initialization list.

Eg:

```
int my_array[3] = {10, 20, 30};
```

That's very useful when we have a set of initial values for our array.
However this approach doesn't work to assign new values to the array once it's declared.

```
my_array = {10, 20, 30};

error: assigning to an array from an initializer list
```

However sometimes we have processes where we need to initialize our arrays several times to some initial values (eg: inside a loop) so I think it would be very useful to be able to use initializer lists to assign values to variables already declared.

My question is: Is there a reason for having such a feature at declaration time but not once the array is declared?
Why does it work in one case but not in the other case?

Comment: This might work using `std::vector<int>` instead of a raw array.

Comment: You might want to check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3438004/7546950

Comment: It really works with vector https://rextester.com/FERF68170.
But array is not dynamic array :) It can't change it's size(we don't know how many elements are in initializer list)

Comment: In addition to @πάνταῥεῖ comment, for fixed size array you could use [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: The array-to-pointer decay applies to operands of `=` so actually this tries to assign a braced list to a pointer, which is not allowed.  The decay can't be changed now, too much code would break.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Arrays are second-class citizens in C++.
They *are* objects,
but they are severely restricted:
they can't be copied,
they are decayed into pointers in various contexts, etc.
Consider using `std::array`,
which is a (fixed-size) wrapper on top of builtin arrays,
but is a first-class citizen which supports various convenience features:

```
std::array<int, 3> my_array = {10, 20, 30};
my_array = {40, 50, 60};
```

This works because, per [[array.overview]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/array.overview#2),

> `std::array` is an aggregate type that can be list-initialized with up
>   to `N` elements whose types are convertible to `T`.

[<kbd>live demo</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/W04UVfAD2IgA3tY3)

This also works with `std::vector`.
Vectors are a different story,
so I am not going to go into details here.

---

If you prefer to insist on builtin arrays,
here's a workaround I designed to enable
assigning a list of values to a builtin array
(respecting value categories),
using template metaprogramming techniques.
A compile-time error is (correctly) raised
if the length of the array and the value list mismatch.
(Thanks to [Caleth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2610810/caleth)'s
comment for pointing this out!)
Note that copying builtin arrays is impossible in C++;
that's why we have to pass the array to the function.

```
namespace detail {
  template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Ints, typename... Args>
  void assign_helper(T (&arr)[N], std::index_sequence<Ints...>, Args&&... args)
  {
    ((arr[Ints] = args), ...);
  }
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename... Args>
void assign(T (&arr)[N], Args&&... args)
{
  return detail::assign_helper(arr, std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

And to use it:

```
int arr[3] = {10, 20, 30};
assign(arr, 40, 50, 60);
```

Now `arr` consists of `40, 50, 60`.

[<kbd>live demo</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZArWwU6MPtMlmy2K)

Comment: You can get `N` from `sizeof...(Args)`, it has to match

Comment: @Caleth Yeah, but the current code already raises a compile-time error automatically when `sizeof...(Args) != N`.

Comment: Good to know about std::array. It works, and I was able to initialize a previously declared array<int, 5> with a braced initializer containing only 2 entries, and, as for a 'C' array, the remaining slots were filled with zeros. (granted, I had to guess that I needed a #include <array>, but, you know ... :-). Thanks @L.F.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a reason for having such a feature at declaration time but not once the array is declared? Why does it work in one case but not in the other case?

The `x = {a, b, ...}` syntax involves a specific type of initializer lists called *copy-list-initialization*. The [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) mentions the possible ways to use copy-list initialization:

- `T object = {arg1, arg2, ...};`   (6)
- `function( { arg1, arg2, ... } )` (7)
- `return { arg1, arg2, ... } ;`    (8)
- `object[ { arg1, arg2, ... } ]`   (9)
- `object = { arg1, arg2, ... }`    (10)
- `U( { arg1, arg2, ... } )`    (11)
- `Class { T member = { arg1, arg2, ... }; };`  (12)

The array syntax that you tried `T myArr[] = {a, b, c...}` works and is numerated as *(6) initialization of a named variable with a braced-init-list after an equals sign*.

The syntax that **doesn't** work for you (`myArr = {a, b, ...}`) is numerated as (10) and it's called *list-initialization in an assignment expression*. The thing about assignment expressions is that the left side must be a so-called *lvalue*, and although arrays are lvalues, they cannot appear on the left side of assignments [as per the specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Assignment).

---

That being said, it wouldn't be very hard to work around assignment by copying an initializer list onto the array as such:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};

  auto itr = arr;
  auto assign = {5, 2, 1};
  std::copy(assign.begin(), assign.end(), itr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Arrays can be initialized with what's called an initialization list.

Well, no.

A class can be initialized with an initialization list they must have a constructor that take an `std::initializer_list`.

**Example**:

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Array are no class, so they can't have a constructor. But they can be initialized with [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

> An aggregate is one of the following types:
>
> - array type
> - ...

And As **L.F.** said : They cannot be copied :

> Assignment
>
> Objects of array type cannot be modified as a whole: even though they
>   are lvalues (e.g. an address of array can be taken), they cannot
>   appear on the left hand side of an assignment operator

Source:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array

That why the `{}` syntaxe works for initialization and not for assignment, because it does not mean the same thing.

Comment: Why the down vote ? If I missed something please let me know.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I would like to note that "Arrays can be initialized with what's called an [initializer] list" doesn't contradict with "Array can be initialized with aggregate initialization."